# Выбрать рандомный цвет из массива для элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, массивы

Есть 3 элемента: квадрат, круг и треугольник.

Есть массив с тремя цветами. Допустим, красный, синий и зеленый.

Моя проблема в том, что я не могу понять как при клике на какую-то кнопку каждый из этих трёх элементов приобрел рандомное значение из этого массива. Т.е. изменил бэкграунд.

Я накалякала вот это (правда, без массива, и не совсем то, что надо, но это всё, что мне удалось сделать):

```
<div id="foo"> foo </div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    function random() {
        return Math.round(Math.random());
    }

    function getRandomColor() {
        return random() ? "grey" : "black";
    }

    function changeColor (a, id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.background = getRandomColor();

        setTimeout(function () {
            changeColor(a, id)
        }, a);
    }

    changeColor(1000, "foo");
});
```

А так то вот нужные три элемента:

```
<div class="sq shape"></div>
<div class="ci shape"></div>
<div class="tr shape"></div>
```

И еще я пробовала вот так:

```
var colors = [
    '#ff0000',
    '#00ff00',
    '#0000ff'
];

var random_color = colors[ Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length) ];
document.getElementsByClassName('sq')[0].style.backgroundcolor =random_color;
```

Но тоже не работает.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту "задачу"

И так, задача решена)

**Если кому интересно решение**: https://jsfiddle.net/ho95g48r/

Comment: "не работает." - понятие даже более абстрактное чем конь в вакууме

Comment: кстати `backgroundcolor` - пишется как "background**C**olor " и цвет в js надо будет писать в виде `RGB(...,...,...)`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хорошо, распишу) Если вместо "getElementsByClassName" использовать див с id, то его цвет меняется после перезагрузки. Есть же использовать класс, - нет. Пусто

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, разве обязательно в rgb?

Comment: `обязательно в rgb` - вот те  ̶к̶р̶е̶с̶т̶! пример https://jsfiddle.net/u0cqbssu/

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, хм, хорошо, тогда буду знать. Может, подскажете, вот с чем - если использовать последний наведенный мною пример (исправив ошибки), все три элемента одного цвета.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/suzLmyvm/1/  ........ если нужны пояснения - скажу чо где и зачем

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ох, как же сложно >< но спасибо, сейчас вычитаю о неизвестных мне методах

Comment: На самом деле там всё просто. И, кстати, если можно допускать тот факт, что цвета могут повторяться, то тогда еще больше упростить можно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, да нет правда слишком сложно) Зачем функция "hexToRgb"?
Приложил подорожник к Вашему примеру:  [https://jsfiddle.net/suzLmyvm/4/](https://jsfiddle.net/suzLmyvm/4/)

Comment: @VasiliyRusin всё-таки `backgroundColor` понимает hex? Казалось, что нет. Поэтому и функция.......... а shuffle к основному массиву не стоило делать. всё-так он может использоваться еще где-то с дефолтными индексами

Comment: @VasiliyRusin с background наверное я спутал "присваивание цвета" и **[сравнение цвета / наличие цвета у элемента](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9421208/6104996)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно легко сделать с использованием jQuery:

1) Сначала берём список элементов [селектором jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp):

```
$('.shape')
```

2) Затем проходим по каждому элементу [функцией `.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('.shape').each( function (index) { ... }  );
```

4) Затем добавляем нужные CSS поля, классы. Например, можно определить массив имён классов, выбрать один случайным образом и использовать [функцию `.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```
// список CSS классов с нужными параметрами
names = [ ... ];
// выбираем случайный элемент массива
var current = names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
// добавляем его какому-нибудь объекту
$( ... ).addClass( current );
```

Итоговый код:

```
// список CSS классов с нужными параметрамиписок классов
names = ['myred', 'light-blue'];

// цикл по всем элементам какого-нибудь класса
$('.shape').each( function (index) {
    // добавить класс случайным образом
    $( this ).addClass( names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)] );
});
```

Вместо установки класса можно ставить любые другие значения. Например, хранить в списке разные цвета и ставить их [функцией .css()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

---

### Update 1. Рабочий пример повторяющихся значений

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // список CSS классов с нужными параметрамиписок классов
    var names = ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"];

    function update () {
        // очистить ранее добавленные классы
        $( ".shape" ).removeClass( "blue yellow red green" );

        // циклически добавить случайный класс
        $('.shape').each( function(index) {
            $( this ).addClass( names [Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)] );
        });
    }

    // вызывать функцию каждые 0.5 сек
    setInterval(update, 500);
});
```

```css
.shape {
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* классы, которые будут случайно добавляться */
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- изначально одинаково пустые объекты -->
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
```

---

### Update 2. Рабочий пример НЕ повторяющихся значений

Для этого нам нужно всего лишь случайным образом отсортировать массив имён и брать значения уже последовательно.

```js
// перемешивает массив случайным образом
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // список CSS классов с нужными параметрамиписок классов
    var names = ["blue", "yellow", "red", "green"];

    function update () {
        // очистить ранее добавленные классы
        $( ".shape" ).removeClass( "blue yellow red green" );

        // перемешать цвета
        var shuffled_names = shuffle(names);

        // циклически добавить элемента массива как класс
        $('.shape').each( function(index) {
            // остаток от деления позволяет проходиться по списку циклически
            // на случай, если число div'в больше числа элементов массива
            $( this ).addClass( shuffled_names [index % names.length] );
        });
    }

    // вызывать функцию каждые 0.5 сек
    setInterval(update, 500);
});
```

```css
.shape {
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* классы, которые будут случайно добавляться */
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- изначально одинаково пустые объекты -->
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<div class="shape"></div>
<!-- проверка, что алгоритм корректно работает на числе div'ов большем количества классов -->
<!-- <div class="shape"></div> -->
```

Comment: Спасибо большое С: Только, будьте добры, объясните что значит " определить массив имён классов"? И откуда в итоговом коде "myArray"?

Comment: @Біпач например, как у меня `names=['myred','light-blue']`, а где-нибудь в CSS: `.myred { background-color: #FF1111; }` и т.д. А благодарности на этом сайте принимаю в виде галочек и стрелок вверх `(:`

Comment: но... вы ответили не на все мои вопросы..

Comment: @Біпач извиняюсь, не заметил. Очевидно, что ‘myArray’ был опечаткой, поправил код. Вроде теперь всё отвечено :)

Comment: @Бiпач Что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, не понятна та часть "добавляем его какому-нибудь объекту". Я пробовала делать вот так: https://jsfiddle.net/suzLmyvm/2 , но всё таки я что-то не так поняла

Comment: @Біпач Ваш код не работает хотя бы потому, что библиотека jQuery не была подключена, на JS Fiddle, как и всюду, это не происходит автоматически. Добавил готовый пример в ответ.

Comment: @Біпач , AivanF. `Update. Рабочий пример` - это не рабочий пример хотя бы потому, что встречается два одинаковых цвета (а может встретиться и больше). Но, как я понимаю, по условию, этого не должно происходить..... Хотя я могу ошибаться.......ну и если будет 20 или 30 цветов или вообще свои генерироваться - то что - на всё создавать классы в css? не всё ими решается))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский странная претензия, в вопросе ничего не было о повторении: `как при клике на какую-то кнопку каждый из этих трёх элементов приобрел рандомное значение из этого массива`. Вопрос был о назначении случайных значений из массива, что и было сделано в ответе. И как уже упоминал, можно использовать не CSS классы, а сразу ставить цвет фона, а его можно не только выбирать из списка, но и генерировать самостоятельно; однако это вне рамок данного вопроса.

Comment: @AivanF. `странная претензия` - в вопросе три варианта, три элемента....... но я говорю же, это не точно. И Біпач может точно это сказать

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ладно, добавил ещё один пример в ответ, если кому-то вдруг нужны неповторяющиеся значения  `:]`

Comment: @AivanF. , спасибо за такой расписанный ответ, мне это очень помогло. И да, в идеале я хотела код без повторяющихся значений, но решила это не указывать, чтобы уже самой додумать как это написать)

Answer (score 1):

У вас опечатка в backgroundcolor -  составные имена **`css`** свойств пишутся в **`js`** в **`camelCase`**. Должно быть так:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sq')[0].style.backgroundColor = random_color;
```

```js
var colors = [
  '#ff0000',
  '#00ff00',
  '#0000ff'
];

console.log(colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);

var random_color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];

document.getElementsByClassName('sq')[0].style.backgroundColor = random_color;
```

```html
<div class="sq shape">1</div>
<div class="ci shape">2</div>
<div class="tr shape">3</div>
```